# Can I set Gravity Form field on required status in Javascript function after click on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravityforms

I implemented my custom gravity form and I need to set one field on required status after clicking on one checkbox.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#choice_5_8_1').change(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                  jQuery("#field_5_9").required(false).change();
             }
        });
   });
```

Is possible before validation of all data and submitting form, please? I tried to use something like that, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#choice_5_8_1').on("change", (function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $("$field_5_9").attr('required', ($(this).attr('required') == "required" ? "" : "required"));
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks, good type but it does not work,  probably I need to consider wordpress hook and no JS

Comment: @MatusVrsansky why doesn't it work, I tested it myself and it works perfectly.

Comment: problem is that i submited my gravity form, pre_submit_form processes some fields, cause checkbox is clicked, but.. when I wanna set them again on default type without required status after clicking on checkbox, it does not work ,, I need to submit my form again

Comment: @MatusVrsansky Fixed now, better?

Comment: do not know yet, I will try that and then  I will send you respond. Do not worry. Thank you for advice